# Curious about setting html content to disappear or scroll with content without covering the content

Tags: html, css

new to coding but wanting to impress with my website.

Currently have an "On this Page" HTML embedded element that I would like to disappear when the user is scrolling down the page.

I have got the element on the left side and know how to set it to fixed. However, this then makes the other content disappear behind the element. So have left the CSS positioning at static, and don't mind that.

Just curious what the code would look like if I wanted to have it scroll with the content but disappear after a certain amount of time or when a user scrolls down in general.

```css
<style>
    .sidebar-content
    {
        position:static;
        background-color:#F9F9F9;
        padding:15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size:20px;
        font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
    }

    h2 {font-weight:400px;
    color: #460E72;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
        } 
    
    a:link {text-decoration:none;
        color:#B6B6BA;
        }
    
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;
        color:#404041;
        }   
    
    a:hover {color:#404041;
        background-color:#eeeeee;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
    
    a:active {text-decoration:none;
        color:#FF6712;}
        
<style> 
        
    .sidebar-content
    {
        top: 0;
        position:fixed;
        width: 256px;
        max-widtH:296px;
        left: - 275px;
        transition:top 0.3s;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-content">
    <h2>On this Page </h2>
    <hr>
     <a href="https://tnucii.weebly.com/blackboard-login--course-access.html#BlackboardLoginSteps">Blackboard Login Steps</a>
    <br />
    <a href="https://tnucii.weebly.com/blackboard-login--course-access.html#TroubleshootingLoginIssues">Troubleshooting Login Issues</a>
    <br />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please inlcude current your code in question?

Comment: Here is an example page of where the "On this Page" menu (https://tnucii.weebly.com/blackboard-login--course-access.html). I will add the code to the question for the specific menu HTML item.

Comment: One problem is that the original site is designed with a table. That kind of design haven't been in use since 15 years back.

Comment: Good to know, @RickardElimää. I am using Weebly Free which obviously has limited me a bit, as I am now learning with the more coding I am learning. Right now not looking to change everything, as I built out the content prior to adding the menu and understand that it may not be possible now but just curious for future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not able to fix only with the css or HTML. You have to use js.

This code will make your object dissapear after the user scrolls down a 100px.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
     $('#divID').hide();
 }
 else {
     $('#divID').show();
 }
 });
```